# Iteratively add columns to the same dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

```
for date in list_of_dates:
    df = *dataframe with identifiers for rows and dates for columns*
    new_column = *a new column with a new date to be added to the df*
    df_incl_new_column = *original df merged with new column*
```

I want to use the 'df_incl_new_column' at the start of the loop as the new 'df' and keep iteratively adding new columns for each date, and using the dataframe with the new column as the start 'df' again and again.

I want to do this for a list of over 20 dates to build a new dataframe with all the new columns.

Each new column has data which changes depending on the previous new column having been added to the df.

What is the best way to do this?

It may be that a for loop is not appropriate but i need to build a dataframe gradually using the latest data in the dataframe to add the next column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```py
df = *dataframe with identifiers for rows and dates for columns*
for date in list_of_dates:
    df['New Column Name'] = *a new column with a new date to be added to the df*
```